# Походження вислову "цілуйте тата в коліщата"?

Tags: етимологія

[Відео-урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNG0ALdVkWM&feature=youtu.be) О.Авраменко російський жартівливий вислів *"пишите письма мелким почерком"* замінює *"цілуйте тата в коліщата"*.

> [Коліщатко](http://sum.in.ua/s/kolishhatko)  Зменш. до коліща.
>
> [Коліща](http://sum.in.ua/s/kolishha)  Невелике колесо (у 1, 3 знач.).

Чому саме такий вираз? Яке походження має приказка *"цілуйте тата в коліщата"*?

Comment: Можу лиш припустити, що _коліщатка_ тут _персні_.

Comment: @follower, навряд, по-моєму.

Comment: Авраменко пояснює що приказка "означає 'все, я пішов', коли завершують розмову". Бачимо що тут є ідея "просторового руху", а коліщата як "маленькі колеса" також стосуються руху, тому можливо "коліщата" тут і справді "колеса" на яких цей тато збирається відїжджати.

Comment: @Sasha Не заперечую, на ЕСУМ відʼзнайшов таке: [ко­лісчатки](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.pdf#page=514) (мн.) «вид вишивки або про­шви на білизні»,

Comment: І так, краще в запитанні пояснити вислів.